# Shading regions inside an mplfinance chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplfinance

I am using matplotlib v 3.7.0, mplfinance version '0.12.9b7', and Python 3.10.

I am trying to shade regions of a plot, and although my logic seems correct, the shaded areas are not being displayed on the plot.

This is my code:

```
import yfinance as yf
import mplfinance as mpf
import pandas as pd

# Download the stock data
df = yf.download('TSLA', start='2022-01-01', end='2022-03-31')

# Define the date ranges for shading
red_range = ['2022-01-15', '2022-02-15']
blue_range = ['2022-03-01', '2022-03-15']


# Create a function to shade the chart regions
def shade_region(ax, region_dates, color):
    region_dates.sort()

    start_date = region_dates[0]
    end_date = region_dates[1]

    # plot vertical lines
    ax.axvline(pd.to_datetime(start_date), color=color, linestyle='--')
    ax.axvline(pd.to_datetime(end_date), color=color, linestyle='--')

    # create fill
    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
    ax.fill_between(pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date), ymin, ymax, alpha=0.2, color=color)
    ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
    ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)


# Plot the candlestick chart with volume
fig, axlist = mpf.plot(df, type='candle', volume=True, style='charles', 
                        title='TSLA Stock Price', ylabel='Price ($)', ylabel_lower='Shares\nTraded', 
                        figratio=(2,1), figsize=(10,5), tight_layout=True, returnfig=True)

# Get the current axis object
ax = axlist[0]

# Shade the regions on the chart
shade_region(ax, red_range, 'red')
shade_region(ax, blue_range, 'blue')


# Show the plot
mpf.show()
```

Why are the selected regions not being shaded, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that, when `show_nontrading=False` (which is the default value when not specified) then the X-axis are *not* dates as you would expect.  Thus the vertical lines and the fill_between that you are specifying **by date** are actually ending up way off the chart.

The simplest solution is to set `show_nontrading=True`.  Using your code:

```py
fig, axlist = mpf.plot(df, type='candle', volume=True, style='charles', 
                       title='TSLA Stock Price', ylabel='Price ($)',
                       ylabel_lower='Shares\nTraded', figratio=(2,1), 
                       figsize=(10,5), tight_layout=True, returnfig=True,
                       show_nontrading=True)

# Get the current axis object
ax = axlist[0]

# Shade the regions on the chart
shade_region(ax, red_range, 'red')
shade_region(ax, blue_range, 'blue')

# Show the plot
mpf.show()
```

[image]

---

There are two other solutions, to the problem, **that allow you to leave `show_nontrading=False`** if that is your preference.

**1.** The first solution is to **use mplfinance's kwargs**, and ***do not*** use returnfig.  Here is the documentation:

- [**`vlines` kwarg**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/using_lines.ipynb),
- [**`fill_between` kwarg**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/fill_between.ipynb).

**This is the prefered solution** since it is always a good idea to let mplfinance do all manipulation of Axes objects, unless there is something that you cannot accomplish otherwise.

And here is an example modifying your code:

```py
red_range = ['2022-01-15', '2022-02-15']
blue_range = ['2022-03-01', '2022-03-15']

vline_dates  = red_range + blue_range
vline_colors = ['red','red','blue','blue']
vline_dict   = dict(vlines=vline_dates,colors=vline_colors,line_style='--')

ymax = max(df['High'].values)
ymin = min(df['Low'].values)

# create a dataframe from the datetime index 
# for using in generating the fill_between `where` values:
dfdates = df.index.to_frame()

# generate red boolean where values:
where_values = pd.notnull(dfdates[(dfdates >= red_range[0]) & (dfdates <= red_range[1])].Date.values)

# put together the red fill_between specification:
fb_red = dict(y1=ymin,y2=ymax,where=where_values,alpha=0.2,color='red')

# generate blue boolean where values:
where_values = pd.notnull(dfdates[(dfdates >= blue_range[0]) & (dfdates <= blue_range[1])].Date.values)

# put together the red fill_between specification:
fb_blue = dict(y1=ymin,y2=ymax,where=where_values,alpha=0.2,color='blue')

# Plot the candlestick chart with volume
mpf.plot(df, type='candle', volume=True, style='charles', 
         title='TSLA Stock Price', ylabel='Price ($)', label_lower='Shares\nTraded', 
         figratio=(2,1), figsize=(10,5), tight_layout=True, 
         vlines=vline_dict, 
         fill_between=[fb_red,fb_blue])
```

[image]

---

**Notice there is** a slight space between the left most vertical line and the shaded area.  That is because the date you have selected ('2022-01-15') is on the weekend (and a 3-day weekend at that).  **If you change the date to '2022-01-14' or '2022-01-18' it will work fine, as shown here:**

[image]

---

---

**2.** The last solution requires `returnfig=True`.  This is ***not the recommended solution*** but it does work.

First, it's important to understand the following:  When `show_nontrading` is *not* specified, it defaults to **`False`**, ***which means*** that, although you see datetimes displayed on the x-axis, **the actual values are the row number of your dataframe**.
[Click here for a more detailed
explanation](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/Mplfinance-Time-Axis-Concerns,-and-Internals-of-Displaying-or-Not-Displaying-Non-Trading-periods).

Therefore,in your code, **instead of specifying dates, you specify the row number where that date appears**.

The simplest way to specify the row number is to use function **`date_to_iloc(df.index.to_series(),date)`** as defined here:

```py
def date_to_iloc(dtseries,date):
    '''Convert a `date` to a location, given a date series w/a datetime index. 
       If `date` does not exactly match a date in the series then interpolate between two dates.
       If `date` is outside the range of dates in the series, then raise an exception
      .
    '''
    d1s = dtseries.loc[date:]
    if len(d1s) < 1:
        sdtrange = str(dtseries[0])+' to '+str(dtseries[-1])
        raise ValueError('User specified line date "'+str(date)+
                         '" is beyond (greater than) range of plotted data ('+sdtrange+').')
    d1 = d1s.index[0]
    d2s = dtseries.loc[:date]
    if len(d2s) < 1:
        sdtrange = str(dtseries[0])+' to '+str(dtseries[-1])
        raise ValueError('User specified line date "'+str(date)+
                         '" is before (less than) range of plotted data ('+sdtrange+').')
    d2 = dtseries.loc[:date].index[-1]
    # If there are duplicate dates in the series, for example in a renko plot
    # then .get_loc(date) will return a slice containing all the dups, so:
    loc1 = dtseries.index.get_loc(d1)
    if isinstance(loc1,slice): loc1 = loc1.start
    loc2 = dtseries.index.get_loc(d2)
    if isinstance(loc2,slice): loc2 = loc2.stop - 1
    return (loc1+loc2)/2.0
```

The function takes as input the data frame index converted to a series.  So the following changes to your code will allow it to work using this method:

```py
# Define the date ranges for shading
red_range = [date_to_iloc(df.index.to_series(),dt) for dt in ['2022-01-15', '2022-02-15']]
blue_range = [date_to_iloc(df.index.to_series(),dt) for dt in ['2022-03-01', '2022-03-15']]

...

    ax.axvline(start_date, color=color, linestyle='--')
    ax.axvline(end_date, color=color, linestyle='--')

...

    ax.fill_between([start_date,end_date], ymin, ymax, alpha=0.2, color=color)
```

Everything else stays the same and you get:
[image]

Comment: +1 for the **VERY** detailed answer! (it's answers like this, that make SO great). I'll make sure I don't have additional questions, before finally accepting the answer. Thanks.

Comment: This is amazing! Im having a similar issue when using returnfig=True, this is the link to the question in this forum, do you know by any chance how to solve this? Thank you!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77687184/show-nontrading-false-in-mplfinance-ruins-my-chart